# A set of three letters {a,b,c}, where ordering matters. The length is defined as the number of letters the string contains.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

a) How many strings of length 4 can you create?

b) How many strings of length 4 do not have consecutive characters being the same?

c) How many strings of length 4 contain neither "cab" nor "bac", or do not have consecutive characters being the same?

***What i've done***

a) $3^4 = 81$

b) First letter = 3 choices. Second letter onwards = 2 choices.

Thus $3 * 2^3 = 24$

c)

***"cab"***

Can be considered as a string with 2 characters however cab can't repeat. Thus

$3P2 = 6$

***"bac"***

Can be considered as a string with 2 characters however bac can't repeat. Thus

$3P2 = 6$

Hence from above, answer is $24 - 8 = 16$ ( 8 not 12 because 'ccab' 'cabb' 'bbac' and 'bacc' have been excluded.)

Is there any error in my calculations?

*edit*: Tagged Pic of question

[image]

Comment: b) You have three options for first letter, two for each other letter (any except previous), thus $3\times 2^3=24$

Comment: @DanielMathias ah understood! how's the rest?

Comment: Not $81-24$, just $24$. Then (c) will be $24-8=16$ (not $24-12$ because 'ccab' 'cabb' 'bbac' and 'bacc' have been excluded)

Comment: How could the answer to $c$ be less than the answer to $b$?  All the good strings from $b$ are good strings for $c$ as well.

Comment: @lulu While I agree with your logical interpretation, I believe "or do not have" was intended to mean "nor do they have". Unless the source provides a list of answers, the intention is uncertain.

Comment: @DanielMathias  Why would you think that?  The phrasing is not ambiguous as it stands.  Of course it's possible that the OP mistyped, in which case they should correct the typo.

Comment: @lulu Because the grammar is poor. The authors used 'neither/nor' but not 'either/or' which makes me doubt the accuracy of their wording.

Comment: @lulu please see post again. attached pic for proof

Comment: @CXY  Well,  post edit I still think my comment stands.  The way I read it, good strings for $c$ are the union of two types of strings;  Strings which contain neither $cab$ nor $bac$ AND strings which have no consecutive repeated letters.  Of course these two sets overlap, $abab$ is of both types, for instance.